# Firebase Phone OTP Authentication not being read automatically

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have been trying so much to read the otp automatically on Firebase I have tried using on Verification Completed but it is not working.

```kotlin
override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
    otp = credential.smsCode
    println("otp is $otp")
}
```

After that I have been used Broadcast Receiver also to the incoming messages but it is also not working.

```kotlin
    package com.example.qrpoc
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
    import android.content.Context
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.content.IntentFilter
    import android.util.Log
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SmsRetriever
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status
    import java.util.regex.Pattern
    class SmsBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
        private val TAG = SmsBroadcastReceiver::class.java.simpleName
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION == intent?.action) {
                val extras = intent.extras
                val status = extras?.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS) as Status
                when (status.statusCode) {
                    CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS -> {
                        // Get SMS message contents
                        val smsMessage = extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE) as String
                        Log.d(TAG, "SMS message: $smsMessage")
                        println("message is $smsMessage")
                        // Extract OTP from SMS message using regex pattern
                        val pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{6}")
                        val matcher = pattern.matcher(smsMessage)
                        if (matcher.find()) {
                            val otp = matcher.group(0)`enter code here`
                            Log.d(TAG, "OTP: $otp")
                            println("otp is $otp")
                            // Use the OTP to verify the phone number
                            // ...
                        }
                    }
                    CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "SMS retrieval timed out")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the manifest file.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
            android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.QrPoc"
            tools:targetApi="31">
            <activity
                android:name=".OTPActivity"
                android:exported="false" />
            <activity
                android:name=".PhoneActivity"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true">
            </activity>
            <receiver
                android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver"
                android:exported="true"
                android:priority="999"
                android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

I have also given permission but do not know where I am getting the problem.
I am getting a message and manually it is working.
The Firebase message is in this format.
`123456 is your verification code for qrpoc-c53aa.firebaseapp.com`
Now my App is in debug state it is not in either play store or dev portals how to solve this problem.